# Regex search contains font-lock strings

Tags: regular-expressions, font-lock

I am searching in a buffer for a regular expression by this snippet:

```
(setq jb-revision-version "\\([[:digit:]]+\\.?\\)")
(setq jb-revision-string "\\(\\(Revision\\|Id\\): +\\)")
(progn
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (setq start (re-search-forward jb-revision-string)
      end (re-search-forward (concat jb-revision-version "+")))
    (setq version (buffer-substring start end))))
```

The result in variable version is this:

```
version
#("0.1.2" 0 5 (face font-lock-comment-face fontified nil))
```

What I want, is the pure string `"0.1.2"` in this case.

Even if I insert `(font-lock-mode -1) ... (font-lock-mode 1)` in my above code, the result still contains some font-lock-info:

```
#("0.1.2" 0 5 (fontified nil))
```

I haven't found any `font-lock-to-string` function, to get rid of that stuff.  Neither did I find a command, to temporarily defontify the buffer before searching.

I haven't found any hints in the Emacs, Emacs-Lisp or the Lisp-Introduction Info manuals.

Comment: does it work to use `buffer-substring-no-properties`?  the description for the `buffer-substring` function says it returns text properties as well as the characters.

Comment: @shoshin YES!  Would you please write it as answer, that I can mark this question solved and give you the credit you deserve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the function `buffer-substring-no-properties`.  In the documentation for `M-x describe-function buffer-substring` it says this:

> This function copies the text properties of that part of the buffer
>   into the result string; if you don’t want the text properties,
>   use `buffer-substring-no-properties` instead.